# Right Shifting Unsigned Integers in C Issue: Vacated Bits Not 0 When Shifting ~0?

Tags: c, bit, bit-shift, kernighan-and-ritchie

To my understanding, when right-shifting an unsigned integer a number of places in C, the empty positions to the left are filled with zeroes.

However, I have been trying to right-shift ~0 (which would be 1111...1111) without any success at all. Trying to right-shift it any amount of places produces the same value except when I store the integer in a variable prior to the shift:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    // Using an expression:
    printf("%u \n", ~0);
    printf("%u \n", ~0 >> 2);
    unsigned int temp = ~0;
    // Using a variable to store the value before shift:
    printf("%u \n", temp);
    printf("%u \n", temp >> 2);

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
4294967295                                                                                   
4294967295                                                                               
4294967295                                                                                  
1073741823
```

Left-shifting ~0 is perfectly fine when performed in either manner. I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: `printf("%u \n", ~0);` is ub, `0` is an `int` literal.

Comment: `~0` is of type `int`.   Printing it using `%u` format gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
~0U >> 2
```

This will make sure that it is unsigned. Otherwise you were having signed operation.

Integral literals are always of type `int` (signed `int`). Now when you were left shifting that it is sign extended.

`%u` expects unsigned int. You have passed a signed int to it. This is Undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The type of the expression `0` is `int`, not `unsigned int`. Therefore, `~0` is the *`int`* with value `0xffffffff` (assuming 32-bit `int`s, which it looks like you have). On most systems, this means `-1`, and right-shifting a signed integer will sign-extend (keep it negative if it starts negative), giving `0xffffffff` again.

When you print it with `%u`, the `printf` function reads this signed `int` with value `-1` as an `unsigned int`, and prints what `0xffffffff` means for an `unsigned int`.

Note that all of this is just what happens on most systems most of the time. This has multiple instances of undefined or implementation-defined behavior (bit pattern of negative `int`s, what right-shifting negative `int`s does, and what the `%u` format specifier means when you pass in an `int` instead of an `unsigned int`).

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code corrects the OPs code and addresses the comments to the question, including the removal of the undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    // Using an expression:
    printf("%u \n", ~0U);
    printf("%u \n", ~0U >> 2);
    unsigned int temp = ~0U;
    // Using a variable to store the value before shift:
    printf("%u \n", temp);
    printf("%u \n", temp >> 2);

    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
4294967295 
1073741823 
4294967295 
1073741823
```